# Error in alignment of text in multi-column in same page

Tags: horizontal-alignment, multicol, alignment, text

the same page is aligned in starting but when i copy paste the code to the bottom , the same texts are not getting aligned.
In the beginning

This is the output i am getting at starting of my document

[image: This is the output i am getting at starting of my document]

And this is the output i am getting when i copy paste the same code at the end of the document

[image: And this is the output i am getting when i copy paste the same code at the end of the document]

```
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\begin{itemize}
\large{\item The cultural programs and art competitions for the underprivileged have been organized to tap their hidden talent and boost them morally.}
\end{itemize}
\section{Detailed project Report}
\subsection{Why Assam?}
\large{Assam is located in the tropical latitudes
(24.30 N and 28.0 N), and eastern longitudes (89.50 E
and 96.10 E), is the most populous state in North-East
India. It is surrounded on three sides by hills and mountains.}
\end{multicols*}
```

Comment: (Off the topic) `\large` for all text seems a bit odd. Maybe you can change the font size of the document referring to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10628/234654)?

Comment: Note that `\large` does not take an argument so `\large{...}`  should be `\large ..` without the `{}` as it is you have an `\item` inside ` {}` group which will break the list processing.  However your problem is unrelated to any of the code you have shown, somewhere between the first image and the second one you have used `\centering` so all the text is centred.